# How to extract data from a new window. WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am working on WPF with MVVM architectural pattern.

But I got stuck on this problem, and I can't seem to resolve it.

I made a new window that is opened and user can input data for an object that should be created when the user presses "ADD", but I know how to open it, but I do not know how to extract the inserted data via textboxes for object creation.

> This is the sample of my new window for inputting data, I tried to
>   implement DataBinding

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,2,0">
        <Label x:Name="NameLB" Content="Reactor Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0" Width="89" RenderTransformOrigin="0.383,0.423"/>
        <Label x:Name="NameErrorLB" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="226,10,0,0" Width="143"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="ReactorNameTB" Text="{Binding ReactorNameText}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="104,10,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117"/>
        <Label x:Name="IdLB" Content="Reactor ID:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,41,0,0" Width="89" RenderTransformOrigin="0.383,0.423"/>
        <Label x:Name="IdErrorLB" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="226,41,0,0" Width="143"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="ReactorIdTB" Text="{Binding ReactorIdText}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="104,41,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117"/>

        <Label x:Name="TypeLB" Content="Reactor Type:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,72,0,0" Width="89" RenderTransformOrigin="0.383,0.423"/>
        <RadioButton x:Name="TypeRB1" IsChecked="{Binding ReactorType1}" Content="Type 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <RadioButton x:Name="TypeRB2" IsChecked="{Binding ReactorType2}" Content="Type 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label x:Name="TypeErrorLB" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="226,72,0,0" Width="143"/>

        <Button x:Name="AddBT" Command="{Binding AddNewReactor}" Content="ADD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,102,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
```

> This my ViewModel implementation with commands

```
        public MyICommand OpenAddReactorWindow { get; set; }
        public MyICommand AddNewReactor { get; set; }
        public MyICommand ExitApplication { get; set; }

        // fields that i tried to bind with DataBinding
        private string reactorNameText;
        private string reactorIdText;
        private string reactorType1;
        private string reactorType2;

        public ReactorViewModel()
        {
            OpenAddReactorWindow = new MyICommand(OpenAddReactor);
            AddNewReactor = new MyICommand(CreatNewReactor);

            ExitApplication = new MyICommand(CloseApplication);
        }



 private void OpenAddReactor()
        {
            AddReactorWindow window = new AddReactorWindow();
            window.Show();
        }
private void CreatNewReactor()
        {
            // here is where I struggle with implementation
        }
```

This is not all of the code it would be a hell of a long post, so I want to keep it short, if something is missing I can upload it.

If someone has a advice , or can explain to me, what I am doing wrong It would be great!

Comment: Your new windows need to have their own view models or at the very least their own properties that utilize inotifypropertychanged so the objects know that the property values have changed after you edit them

Comment: Hmm, I've read about it, but I am not that familiar with the implementation of it

Comment: So I should create a new ViewModel for my new Window in it transfer my fields that I DataBinded, and there implement adding a new object?

Comment: In your view models you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged events on your property setter methods. This would tell the view model that you updated the value of a given property -- otherwise you may change the value in the window but the view model never really knows it happened. It detects property value changes from the view and fires an event that notifies the view model about the change in value so it can react accordingly. Here is more about it from a WPF point of view: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification

Comment: This is not MVVM. A view model is not supposed to create a new window.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 ViewModel in this question. One is used for your main window(which you alread have) and the other is used for your new window(this is a new one you need create).

Main Window ViewModel

```cs
NewWindowViewModel vm = new NewWindowViewModel();
private void CreatNewReactor()
{
    NewWindow nw = new NewWindow();
    nw.DataContext = vm;
    if(nw.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        //do something
        //you can also pass new window databinding into main ViewModel
        //for example: something = vm.something
    }
}
```

Comment: So I should create a new class named NewWindowViewModel, as I've done with WindowViewModel

Comment: @Stefan Correct. Just a new ViewModel for your new window. Of course it can be any name you want.